# Failed to lookup view "search"

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

Pretty new to programming; this is my first full app. I'm getting the following error with trying to run this: Pretty confused as to what's going on and would appreciate any help! Thanks! I've added ____ to differentiate between the 3 code files

Error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "search"
    at Function.app.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:495:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:756:7)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app.js:7:6
    at callbacks (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.expressInit [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:31:5)
```

Code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("search");
});

app.get("/results", function(req, res){
    var query = req.query.search;
    var url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=" + query + "&interval=1min&apikey=VIR65NRTVJZQHZGC";
    request(url, function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body)
            res.render("results", {data: data});
        }
    });
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server has started!!!");
});
```

---

```
<h1>Find Stock Value</h1>

<form action="/results" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter stock ticker" name="search">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

```
<h1> Results </h1>

<%= data["search"].forEach(function(stock) { %>
    <li><%= stock["close"]%></li>

<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

improper file structure, resolved on own